# GTK3 Folder Name dialog is white on white

Tags: configuration, gui, gtk3

Since browsers on Xubuntu started using GTK3 instead of GTK2, and when saving a file, the dialog for entering a new folder name is white on white and hence unreadable.

[image: GTK3 folder name dialog is white on white]

I gather this might be changed in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`, but I am unsure under what element ID name that would be.

Furthermore, is there **a system wide `gtk.css` file** that solves this issue for all users on this system?

Comment: Choose another theme.

Comment: @IporSircer OK, but how am I supposed to choose a GTK3 theme when Xubuntu only has a tool to select GTK2 themes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the culprit. `gtk-theme-config` serves both GTK2 and GTK3 applications. Resetting **Custom menu colours** to its defaults resolves the issue. I opened a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk-theme-config/+bug/1780745) against `gtk-theme-config`.
Xubuntu LTS 16.04 comes with version `1.2.1-0ubuntu1`.
The bug persists in the latest version `1.2.2-1`.

[image: gtk-theme-config]

Answer (score 1):

You should have `/etc/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` and possibly `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`. You can create the latter as a simple text file if it is not already present.

It's probable that `/etc/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` looks like this:

```
[Settings]
gtk-theme-name = Ambiance
gtk-icon-theme-name = ubuntu-mono-dark
gtk-sound-theme-name = ubuntu
gtk-icon-sizes = panel-menu-bar=24,24
```

You can change the gtk3 theme in that file as well as in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`. I like to have different gtk3 themes for user and for root (as a gentle reminder that I'm working as root).

As suggested in the comments to your question, changing themes may help overcome the white-on-white issue.

Comment: `/etc/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` has the contents as described. I happy to experiment with other GTK3 themes, if only I knew which are available. In Xubuntu there is by default no app installed to configure GTK3 themes. Again, I am happy to install such app, if I knew which.

Comment: `apt search gtk-theme` will list themes available from the repositories. `apt show numix-gtk-theme`, for example, will tell you if that theme has code for gtk2 and gtk3 aspects.